# Compile rust dependency with debug flag during test

Tags: rust

I am using a Rust dependency which allows being built with a `--debug` or `--verbose` flag.
[image]

I am running my test as follows:

`cargo test --package mw-btc-swap --bin mw-btc-swap -- grin::grin_core::test::test_fin_tx --exact --nocapture`

Now my question is how can I configure cargo to only compile this specific dependency with the desired flag. I tried using `RUSTFLAGS=--debug` environment variable but then the flag seems to be passed to all compilations which makes most of them fail, as they don't support this flag.
I have also looked through https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html in hope I could somehow specify the flags in the `cargo.toml` which doesn't seem to be the case.